# How can I make an audio sound play only once using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

So I have a div that plays an mp3 sound when it is clicked. Instead of playin once. It continues to play over and over again. The snippet of code is:

```
  $(".g-contain").click(function() {
       audioElement.play();
    });
```

This may be irrelevant but I figure I should show you the overall code:

```
      /* set no cache */
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });


          var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8xaglyd48vbnq1/pacman_chomp.mp3?dl=1');

        audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            this.play();
        }, false);


      $.getJSON("scripts/data", function(data) {
        var html = [];

        /* loop through array */
        $.each(data, function(index, g) {

        $(".container").append(
            "<div class='g-details'><div class='name'>" +
              g.name + "</div>);

 // And finally my click call is here

 $(".g-contain").click(function() {
      audioElement.play();
 });
```

Not sure why the mp3 file keeps playing when `g-contain` div is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to this code:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.play();
}, false);
```

You attached an event listener to the audio element to re-`play` when the playing is `ended`. So once it's played (with click) it will play infinitely.

From the [MDN **ended** event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended):

> **ended**
>
> The ended event is fired when playback or streaming has stopped
>   because the end of the media was reached or because no further data is
>   available.

Just get rid of this code.

Comment: Great, glad it helps.